# Nested Array with LEFT JOIN TABLE extracting results

Tags: php, sql, foreach, multidimensional-array

I may be doing this all wrong, but I really need help grasping how to work through nested arrays. I have two tables User and Reviews.

This is the SELECT statement I am using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `reviews` 
ON users.userId = reviews.user_id 
WHERE installation_id = $installation_id
```

This is how I receive my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 60
            [usersEmail] => gggg@gmail.com
            [password] => 0Vg+sLdlALchd39l+3K3QXFZlvh79bwqXFp/J3nIR+o=
            [usersName] => Lauren 
            [role] => scout
            [id] => 1
            [user_id] => 60
            [client_id] => 62
            [comments] => This person was extremely professional and went above and beyond. Her pricing was reasonable.
            [stars] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 60
        [usersEmail] => gggg@gmail.com
        [password] => 0Vg+sLdlALchd39l+3K3QXFZlvh79bwqXFp/J3nIR+o=
        [usersName] => Lauren Rothlisberger
        [role] => scout
        [id] => 2
        [user_id] => 60
        [client_id] => 1
        [comments] => She was pretty good. I have a couple small complaints but overall decent experience. 
        [stars] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 63
        [usersEmail] => proth@mail.com
        [password] => 
        [usersName] => Paul Rothlisberger
        [role] =>
        [id] => 
        [user_id] => 
        [client_id] => 
        [comments] => 
        [stars] => 
    )
```

)

Something about this doesn't make sense to me. I thought it would be more like

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [userId] => 60
        [usersEmail] => gggg@gmail.com
        [password] => 0Vg+sLdlALchd39l+3K3QXFZlvh79bwqXFp/J3nIR+o=
        [usersName] => Lauren Rothlisberger
        [role] => scout
        [id] => 2
        [user_id] => 60
        [client_id] => 1
                Array [0](
                      [comments]  
                      [stars] ) 
    )
```

How do I get that Array? And furthermore how them do I iterate through the User then show foreach User all their comments and stars.

I also can't figure out how I would find say the stars for UserId = 60 then give the average stars for that user.

Thanks for any help you can offer me. I am obviously missing some basics. Please don't point me to the documentation I have been through it and can't apply it.

Comment: using only mysql query you can't do this you have to execute loop on top of your results to prepare the array like this

Comment: update your code what you tried so far

Comment: Many PHP frameworks (Laravel, CakePHP, etc) have the ability to organize table relations in query output as you expect, but SQL alone is capable of only 2 dimensional result sets. If you executed the same query in a plain MySQL client, your result would be strictly tabular.  Using raw PHP, you need to code it yourself.

Comment: So I have completely misunderstood the point of a being able to JOIN tables? Could you give me an example. Why should I have a table users_reviews?

Answer (score 0):

as you've noticed each record returned is a complete record and when there are many to one relationships involved you get one record for each combination.

when i encounter this, i apply the following short loop to pack the results in something more similar to the second format but it includes duplicates the user level fields each time.  this way i can easily count the number of sub items for each user, do intermediate sorting or other operations by using a nested foreach on the output side.

```
$results = array();
$results_raw = db.select(' ... the select statement ');
if (is_array($results_raw)) foreach ($results_raw as $result) {
    $results[$result['userId']] = $result;
}
```